# Redisson executing previous jobs on the schedule of newly submitted jobs

Tags: java, redis, redisson

At first I scheduled 5 jobs (old_job) they executed successfully. After that I scheduled another 5 jobs(new_job) but this time the previous 5 jobs got executed on the schedule I gave for new job. Can anyone explain me this behaviour of redisson and point where I am making the mistake.

```
public class Main {

private final static int NO_OF_JOBS = 5;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Config config = new Config();
    config.useClusterServers()
            .addNodeAddress("http://127.0.0.1:7000", "http://127.0.0.1:7001", "http://127.0.0.1:7002");
    RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config);
    RExecutorService e =  redisson.getExecutorService("w1");//redisson.getExecutorService("w1");

    for (int j = 0; j < NO_OF_JOBS; j++) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 1;
        //System.out.println("hour, minute" + hour + ", " + minute);
        ((RScheduledExecutorService) e).schedule(new RunnableTask(j + 1), CronSchedule.dailyAtHourAndMinute(hour, minute));
    }
  }
}

//new_job
public class RunnableTask implements Runnable {
    private int job_no;
    RunnableTask(int job_no) {
        this.job_no = job_no;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
            System.out.println("This is task no " + job_no);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

//old_Job

public class RunnableTask implements Runnable {
    private static volatile int i = 0;
    private long anyParam;
    public RunnableTask() {
    }
    RunnableTask(long anyParam) {
        this.anyParam = anyParam;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
            i++;
            System.out.println(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

For this experiment I runned 4 redissonnodes in standalone mode with configuration as described below.

```
{
   "clusterServersConfig":{
      "nodeAddresses":[
         "redis://127.0.0.1:7001",
         "redis://127.0.0.1:7002",
         "redis://127.0.0.1:7003"
      ],
   },
   "threads":10,
   "executorServiceWorkers": {"w1":10},

}
```

I need help in deducing this behaviour of redisson.